# Assigning a set of values onto different sets of labels

Tags: c#

Basically, it's a mastermind game. I want to get the player's guesses to print onto a list of labels if the guesses are wrong when the player clicks on the button. Problem is that there are a lot of labels and I wonder whether there is an easier method to do that without manually coding *every single label*.

FYI the players guesses would be in values ranging from 1 - 6 e.g. 1234 
then it would be checked with the random number generator. Guesses would then be displayed in labels for each digit individually.

I am an amateur programmer still learning the ropes. Appreciate if anyone of you guys could help me.

Comment: Stawho beat me to it... But just saw the c# tag anyway. Oh well

Answer (score 0):

Make a UserControl to wrap each set of 4 labels, with a property that represents the value (e.g. "1234") and controls the labels. Then, instead of several rows of labels, you just put several instances of your UserControl on the Form.